# In the pipeline outputs the variables is not replaced with their value but remain as macros

Tags: bash, variables, gitlab, pipeline

Instead of `$SNAPSHOT_NAME` on the green line,
I want the value of the variable to be:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UEmi.png]

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557); post the text itself, in [code block format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) so it's readable. Also, please explain more clearly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I do not understand, the output shows that `SNAPSHOT_NAME` has been replaced by `releasedpatch8`

Comment: I need it to be replaced on the green line as well

Comment: Green lines are written by you